# Set elasticsearch match precendence

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, searchkick

So if a user search with the word `covid`, i want all those results first, where title of the sentence starts with word `covid` and then I want all those items where in other parts of the title have the word have word `covid`. How can I achieve this?

I want more specific answer, how to do that with searchkick.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default mapping, You can use the `bool` query with two `should` clause, one with `match` on the `text` and another is `prefix` query on `.keyword` subfield as shown in below example.

**Index sample documents**

```
{
    "name" : "foo bar"
}
{
    "name" : "bar foo"
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name" : "foo"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "name.keyword": "foo"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Search results**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "71998426",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.1823215,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "foo bar"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "71998426",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.18232156,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "bar foo"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**Note: first result, having `foo bar` is scored much higher and comes first in the search hits.**

Answer (score 0):

you can even use boost i guess little modification to @Amit code

````
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "name" : "covid",
                            "boost" : 0.5
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "prefix": {
                            "name.keyword": "foo",
                            "boost" : 1.0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }```
````